# Is a scoped type statement possible?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to do the following:

```
foo = bar
    where
        type A = (Some, Huge, Type, Sig)

        meh :: A -> (A, A) -> A
```

I only need to use this custom type inside the where clause, so it does not make sense to define it globally.

Comment: I suppose this is assuming that `meh` is not polymorphic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't possible. Why not just define it above the function? You don't have to export it from the module (just use an explicit export list).

By the way, if you really do have a type that big, it's probably a sign that you should factor it into smaller parts, especially if you have a lot of tuples as your example suggests; data-types would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, there's one, slightly ridiculous, way to approximate this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

foo :: forall abbrv. (abbrv ~ (Some, Huge, Type, Sig))
    => abbrv -> abbrv
foo x = meh x (x, x)
  where meh :: abbrv -> (abbrv, abbrv) -> abbrv
        meh x y = {- ... -}
```

I can't really recommend enabling two language extensions just for the sake of abbreviating types in signatures, though if you're already using them (or GADTs instead of type families) I suppose it doesn't really hurt anything.

Silliness aside, you should consider refactoring your types in cases like this, as ehird suggests.

Comment: Very cute! Are the scoped type variables really needed? (It seems like the type equality is the really clever bit, and that could be moved into the type of `meh`.)

Comment: @DanielWagner: Only the equality constraint is required for the abbreviation trick, yes. But the question was specifically about a *scoped* type, so not extending it to the `where` clause would have been dissatisfying. :]

Comment: @ehird: It's not necessary. This is still rank-1 polymorphism, the explicit `forall` is only there to extend the scope to the `where` clause.

Comment: @C.A.McCann: It's necessary because `forall` doesn't work out-of-the-box. `ExplicitForAll` would also work, of course.

Comment: @ehird: `ScopedTypeVariables` also implies `ExplicitForAll`, I believe. The example code (with a few definitions filled in) works, at any rate.

Comment: @C.A.McCann: Huh, you're right; I must have had some other problem compiling it. My mistake.